# A tool for converting database tables to entity java classes for hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need a tool for converting database tables to entity java files for hibernate.

There are 20 tables (mysql) and I don't want to copy table's column name to my Java file and so on.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hibernate Tools](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html).

Keep in mind that entity classes / mappings that Database Reverse Engineering tool will generate may not be ideal (depending on complexity of your database) and you'll have to manually update them.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120188/generating-hibernate-hbm-xml-files-entities-classes-from-existing-db-schema) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sql schema, you can use https://converter.aldoraweb.com to convert it[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse DALI, Netbeans jpa-plugin and Oracle JDevelopper.